# Angular 8 how to use Animations transitions and triggers in a service.ts file

Tags: angular, angular-services

Angular 8 how to use Animations transitions and triggers in a service.ts file?
Here is the reference of angular animation that is working ok in the component
but I want to use this in a service that is imported in component flie.

https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers

Comment: Can you mark it as answer if it answered your question please?

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-example-bs8l5x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I am assuming when you say animations in service, you want to reuse the animations.

You can export the animation from an animations file.
[image]

Then in you component, you can import the animation.

[image]

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: ast.states is undefined
AnimationTrigger@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:5205:9
buildTrigger@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:5190:12
registerTrigger@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:8127:23
createRenderer/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:97981:32
createRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:97977:27
createRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:88458:49.....

Comment: @sandeepkumar. Fixed it. There is a stackblitz which has a working demo.